# Golang: json Unmarshal fails to unpack simple example

Tags: go

I cannot get my head around this problem. I have a simple struct, and another struct that uses it twice:

```
type Range struct {
    Position int `json:"position"`
    Length   int `json:"length"`
}

type TwoRanges struct {
    From Range `json:"from"`
    To   Range `json:"to"`
}
```

and the following json sample in file "ranges.json":

```
{
"from:": {
    "position": 348,
    "length": 15
},
"to": {
    "position": 737,
    "length" : 10
}
}
```

I try unmarshalling the sample in the following code:

```
func main() {
    buffer, err := ioutil.ReadFile("ranges.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    var sample TwoRanges
    if err = json.Unmarshal(buffer, &sample); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", sample)
}
```

The output is

```
{{0 0} {737 10}}
```

Somehow, only the half of the struct is unpacked.

1. Is it a bug, or am I doing something wrong?
2. Is there a "verbose mode" for the encoding/json package which would tell me what went wrong with the unmarshaller? It's not the first time that I've had mysterious problems with that package.

Comment: the "from:" should be "from" in your `ranges.json`

Comment: @simon_xia Wow! Thank you for your sharp eyes! This solves my problem, at least for now. Please, make an answer of your comment. Do you know of any tool that would help me find mistakes like this (like the "verbose mode" that I imagined above)?

Comment: this is not syntax error, sorry for my limited knowledge to find a tool out there to avoid this :(  @user44168

Answer (score 2, accepted):

note that:

the **"from:"** should be "from" in your `ranges.json`

Answer (score -1):

The json has bad formatted, 
look the colon afer from : 
{
"from:": {
   .....